# How do i return the remainder of a string?

Tags: php, substr

I have some text in string which i want to split in half but so it breaks after a complete word.

```
$text = "This is a string of test text";
```

I used substr() which was great but cut a word in half.

> substr($text, 0, 15);
>
> resulted in outputting: "This is a strin"

So I found and tried this approach:

```
$part1=$text;
if (preg_match('/^.{1,15}\b/s', $text, $match))
{
  $part1=$match[0];
}
```

which gave me "This is a"

PERFECT!

...but how do i get "string of test text" in another variable?

Comment: “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's lazy but as you have the part 1, you can get part 2 like this:

```
$part1=$text;
if (preg_match('/^.{1,15}\b/s', $text, $match))
{
  $part1=$match[0];
}
$part2 = str_replace($part1, "", $text);
```

It removes the part 1 from the string and as a result you'll have part 2

Better solution (but a little bit harder) is to get part 2 index by capturing the offset in preg_match method. It gives you the position of the matching string:

```
$part1=$text;
if (preg_match('/^.{1,15}\b/s', $text, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
  $part1 = $match[0][0];
  $part2 = substr($text, $match[0][1] + strlen($part1), strlen($text) - strlen($part1));
}
```

The second solution might need some fixes.

Comment: The lazy option worked a treat! Thank you very much Parsa!

Answer (score 0):

Using `wordwrap` which will wrap using newline and not cut words by default:

```
$text = wordwrap($text, 15);
```

Yields:

```
This is a
string of test
text
```

You can use that string or get each line as array elements:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
```

Then you can use them individually, or if you only want the first part and then all remaining:

```
$first = array_shift($lines);
$remaining = implode(" ", $lines);
```

---

As for the regex, use capture groups `()` to get the first part and remaining:

```
preg_match('/^(.{1,15}\b)(.*)/s', $text, $match);
```

Yields the complete match in `0` and then the capture groups in `1` and `2`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a string of test text
    [1] => This is a 
    [2] => string of test text
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** I disagree that the statement that the string `This is a` is *perfect*, purely on the basis that the substring length is one third of the total string length and you could get closer to *the middle* if you broke after `string` instead?

```
This is a           ==> 9
string of test text ==> 19

This is a string  ==> 16
of test text      ==> 13
```

So, bearing that in mind, I would use the following:

```
// String to split in ~half
$text = "This is a string of test text";

// Set initial lengths to the half way point of the string, rounding down
$max = $min = $length = floor(strlen($text) / 2);

// Loop through a maximum of `half total string length` times
//   > Half because we're doubling the count by [inc/dec]rementing
//     $min and $max on each loop
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

    // Create the pattern; using sprintf so it's a bit easier to read
    // We're also post [inc/dec]rementing the variables $min and $max
    $pattern = sprintf('/^(.{%d,%d})\b(.*)$/', $min--, $max++);
    
    // Check to see if there was a match
    if( preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches) ){
        break;
    }

    // If no match by the end of the loop set matches to FALSE
    // This would happen if, for example, there were no boundaries (\b)
    $matches = FALSE;
}

// Code without comments...

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $pattern = sprintf('/^(.{%d,%d})\b(.*)$/', $min--, $max++);
    if( preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches) )
        break;
    $matches = FALSE;
}
```

**Patterns iterated**

The match, in this case is found on the third loop...

```
/^(.{14,14})\b(.*)$/
/^(.{13,15})\b(.*)$/
/^(.{12,16})\b(.*)$/
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "This is a string of test text"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "This is a string"
  [2]=>
  string(13) " of test text"
}
```

Comment: Oh i'm sure it wasn't perfect, but it was for my needs, thank you though, Steven!